# htaccess same name file and folder not working when accessing folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a file named friends.html.

Then I have a friends folder

My htaccess works fine , localhost/friends/ opens my friends.html as I wanted

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Now, if I have mary.html inside my friends/best/ folder, how do I get localhost/friends/best/mary/ to go to localhost/friends/best/mary.html?

That does not work with the current file- 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is just a two depth directory, then you can add the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2/$3.html
```

As I see in your examples, the only Rule you may need is the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.html
```

Which does the following:

```
/friends -> /friends.html
/friends/john/ -> /friends/john.html
/friends/best/mary/ -> /friends/best/mary.html
/friends/of/my/friends/george/ -> /friends/of/my/friends/george.html
```